# Ruby from two dimension to one dimension array

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
arr = [
 "Assignment:Chapter 1 Code Exercises (Real)",
 [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
 "Assignment:Chapter 2 Code Exercises (Real)", 
 [93, 75, 100, 100, 100, 55, 75, 100],
 "Assignment:Chapter 3 Code Exercises (Real)",
 [100, 80, 100, 100, 90, 85, 65, 100],
 "Assignment:Chapter 4 Code Exercises (Real)",
 [100, 90, 100, 100, 95, 100, 75, 70],
 "Assignment:Chapter 5 Code Exercises (Real)",
 [50, 100, 100, 100, 60, 70, 90, 100],
 "Assignment:Chapter 6 Code Exercises (Real)",
 [0, 85, 100, 100, 60, 85, 70, 85, 100],
 "Assignment:Chapter 14 Code Exercises (Real)",
 [75, 90, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100],
 "Assignment:Chapter 15 Code Exercises (Real)",
 [97, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100]
]
```

I would like to convert this to:

```
[
 ["Assignment:Chapter 1 Code Exercises (Real)", 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100], 
 ["Assignment:Chapter 2 Code Exercises (Real)", 93, 75, 100, 100, 100, 55, 75, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 3 Code Exercises (Real)", 100, 80, 100, 100, 90, 85, 65, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 4 Code Exercises (Real)", 100, 90, 100, 100, 95, 100, 75, 70],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 5 Code Exercises (Real)", 50, 100, 100, 100, 60, 70, 90, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 6 Code Exercises (Real)", 0, 85, 100, 100, 60, 85, 70, 85], 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 14 Code Exercises (Real)", 75, 90, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 15 Code Exercises (Real)", 97, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100]
]
```

`flatten` so too "flat". I also tried flatten(1).

Comment: Yes...typo. Its fixed now.

Comment: I reformatted your arrays for readability and set the variable `arr` equal to the given array. That way readers can refer to `arr` in answers and comments without having to define it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array.each_slice(2).map { |(x,y)| [x] + y }
#=> [["Assignment:Chapter 1 Code Exercises (Real)", 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],               
#    ["Assignment:Chapter 2 Code Exercises (Real)", 93, 75, 100, 100, 100, 55, 75, 100],                   
#    ["Assignment:Chapter 3 Code Exercises (Real)", 100, 80, 100, 100, 90, 85, 65, 100],                   
#    ["Assignment:Chapter 4 Code Exercises (Real)", 100, 90, 100, 100, 95, 100, 75, 70],                   
#    ["Assignment:Chapter 5 Code Exercises (Real)", 50, 100, 100, 100, 60, 70, 90, 100],            
#    ["Assignment:Chapter 6 Code Exercises (Real)", 0, 85, 100, 100, 60, 85, 70, 85, 100],          
#    ["Assignment:Chapter 14 Code Exercises (Real)", 75, 90, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100],             
#    ["Assignment:Chapter 15 Code Exercises (Real)", 97, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100]]
```

Comment: You could do `map(&:flatten)` as well, instead of manually constructing the resulting format in the block.

Comment: ...or `{ |(x,y)| [x, *y] }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland or `{ |x,y| *_ = x,*y }` OR `(1..arr.size).step(2).map {|i| [arr[i - 1],*arr[i]] }`

Comment: @engineersmnky, just don't suggest `{ [_1, *(_2)] }`!

Answer (score 2):

```
> Hash[*a].map(&:flatten)
=> 
[["Assignment:Chapter 1 Code Exercises (Real)", 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 2 Code Exercises (Real)", 93, 75, 100, 100, 100, 55, 75, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 3 Code Exercises (Real)", 100, 80, 100, 100, 90, 85, 65, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 4 Code Exercises (Real)", 100, 90, 100, 100, 95, 100, 75, 70],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 5 Code Exercises (Real)", 50, 100, 100, 100, 60, 70, 90, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 6 Code Exercises (Real)", 0, 85, 100, 100, 60, 85, 70, 85, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 14 Code Exercises (Real)", 75, 90, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100],
 ["Assignment:Chapter 15 Code Exercises (Real)", 97, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100]]
```

where `a` is the first array above.

Alternatively, taking @CarySwoveland's recommendation:

```
a.each_slice(2).map(&:flatten)
```

is more efficient w/ both time and memory, and doesn't require the strings to be unique.

Comment: Clever(!), but it does create a temporary object (hash), which can be avoided.

Comment: Maybe that would be the most elegant suggestion: Just to use a hash `Hash[*a]`. It doesn't make much sense to have two different kind of data together in the nested arrays.